Cut out that infernal racket! Turn the [volume] down to 0
For tag volume:

Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
It is very ambiguous. In addition to the audio meaning and the geometric meaning cited in the tag excerpt itself, there is also "trading volume" (finance) and "disk volume" (hardware), both of which are also used in existing questions.

Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
On its own, I don't think the definitions (math, hardware, and finance) are inherently programming related. Maybe Docker, but then we also already have docker-volume for Docker questions.

Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
No, because it means at least 4 different things. Am I finding the volume of a 3d object? Mounting a disk volume? Doing stuff with Docker? Adjusting audio amplitude?

Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?
No. After a quick survey of the newest 50 questions:

20 are about audio
5 are about math

Meaning that 50% even fit with the current tag usage guidance.



Also, not sure if it matters if we're burninating it, but there is plagiarized text in the tag wiki. Source 1, Source 2. They are linked, but not attributed, and the wiki is mostly copied text.

Can I include [tag:volumes] too, or is that a separate post?

Volumes 2: Electric Burningoo

Since they're big, it's probably better to keep them separated

Burninate [volume] -- doesn't go to 11.

1856 questions... is it really worth everyone's time? Is the tag really causing harm actively or is it just one of those stupid "filler" tags that adds nothing to the question?

@Lundin many 1k-2k tags that don't get burninated promptly become 4k-5k after 2-3 years... Generally it's best to nuke those tags early while they're still doable considering the usual number of burnination contributors.

@bad_coder Burning tags for burnination's own sake fills no purpose though. The tag should to be harmful and misleading. If it's merely a useless thing just sitting there, why bother.

@Lundin having noise in the tag system is a nuisance and it's proportional to the tags' off-topic attractiveness... I haven't ascertained how much of a VLQ magnet this tag is, but however much it should go. Prioritizing what gets does first otoh is the handling mod's prerogative. (And it's not just me saying, we've done hundreds of comparable burns over the years.)

@bad_coder Except people don't post crap questions just because a certain tag exists. They type in a crap question and then find some tags for it. Meaning that the crap question will end up on the site regardless of what tags there are available.

But nobody is talking about cleaning up that crap question. When editing, people are instructed to edit everything they can and not just what they're fixating on. The same should apply to tag cleanup.

@Gimby That's exactly how manual tag burnination works: edit and fix everything that needs fixing, close if appropriate. However, doing that to 1855 questions is no small task.

Upvote just for the wonderful title

I muted my speakers before visiting this question from the Meta side bar

The [volume] of bad questions goes to 11.
